# Financial Mathematics. Specific Nominal Discount Rate Question

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The question is from Marcel P Finan's "A Basic Course in the Theory of Interest and Derivatives Markets: Preparation for the Actuarial Exam FM/2".

Suppose that $100$ is deposited into a savings account, earning at a discount rate of $0.15\%$ biweekly, at the beginning of year $2006$.
(a) Find the nominal annual discount rate.

My main attempt at (a):

$(1 - 0.0015)^{-1} = (1 - d^{26}/26)^{-26}$

$1.001502253 = (1 - d^{26}/26)^{-26}$

$1.001502253^{-(1/26)} = (1 - d^{26}/26)^{-26}$

$0.999942266 = 1 - d^{26}/26$

$d^{26} = 0.001501083$

However, this is ***not*** the correct answer in the book. :(

The correct answer in the book: $3.9$%

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: It says the answer is 3.9% in the back of the book.

Comment: Looks like this book assumes $(1+0.15\%)^{26}\approx 1+3.97\%.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yearly nominal discount rate d is

$$d=m\cdot ((1+e)^{\frac{1}{m}}-1),$$

where $m=26$ is the number of compounding periods in a year and $e$ the effective yearly discount rate. The formula is derived from the well known formula $e=(1+\frac{d}m)^m-1$.

Now the yearly effective discount rate is $e=(1+b)^{m}-1$, where $b$ is the biweekly nominal discount rate. Next we insert the term for $e$ into the formula for $d$.

$$d=m\cdot ((1+(1+b)^{m}-1)^{\frac{1}{m}}-1)=m\cdot ((1+b)^{m})^{\frac{1}{m}}-1)=m\cdot (1+b-1)=m\cdot b$$

Comprehensible? If yes, can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Nice to here. You're welcome.